# Unable to load asset image in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the code as follows:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 158, 202, 239),
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
        height: 250,
        width: 180,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: const Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/heart.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I receive is as follows:

> The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec: 
> Unable to load asset: "assets/heart.png".
>
> Exception: Asset not found

How can I fix it?

My *pubspec.yaml* file is as follows:

```yaml
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/joker.jpeg
    - assets/heart.png
```

Comment: Does the assets folder and heart.png file exist in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the app and rerun the app. Do not do a hot restart (sometimes this will work).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should [add the assets to your `pubspec.yaml`](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images).

Comment: yes its added in the pubspec.yaml

Comment: # The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/joker.jpeg
    - assets/heart.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `pubspec.yaml` file to include the assets you want to use.

Open the `pubspec.yaml` file and add the following lines:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/heart.png
```

Comment: yes its added in the pubspec.yaml

Comment: # The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/joker.jpeg
    - assets/heart.png

Comment: `#`
 in the beginning of the line means it is commented out.

Comment: It is not commented out.

Comment: please add yaml file content to your question.

Comment: what is folder structure for assets?

Comment: Yes, its added.

Comment: The assets folder is sibling to lib folder. assets/heart.png

Comment: it should be at the same level as lib.

Comment: Thats correct. It is at the same level.